# Coldfusion IIS 7 custom 404 blank page

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion, http-status-code-404

In order to respond in any cfm with a cfheader statuscode=404, in web.config I have setup this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

That's works great.

To respond with a custom page when the client access to an inexsistent page, I have setup a Custom 404 page to a cfm in IIS7 manager but it respond with a blank page (with 404 code) and not my custom cfm page.

How can I configure IIS to respond with a custom page AND passthough from cfheader ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this link that answers a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18927484/2788098).  The solution was found on a server running ColdFusion 9 Standard but I believe the result will be the same on ColdFusion 10, since my own problem - discussed in another thread - began with that version.

Long story short:  For problem-free operation you must put a 404 handler under the web root of your site and use IIS Error Pages to specify that ColdFusion page as the 404 handler for the site.  Complete details in the link.

Answer (score -3):

Control Panel, Admin tools, Sites, Error pages.