# onMissingTemplate returns blank page, possible conflict with IIS

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, iis-8

I've been trying to set a custom 404 page to show a user-friendly message when the page is missing. That said, my web server (IIS 8) does not process .cfm pages, hence I've written a simple testing script to handle cfm pages onMissingTemplate withing Application.cfc

```
<cffunction name="onMissingTemplate" returnType="boolean" output="true">
<cfargument name="targetPage" type="string" required=true/>
<cfset var emails = "abcd@hotmail.com,abcd@gmail.com">

<cftry>
    <!--- Log all errors. --->
    <cflog type="error" text="Missing template: #Arguments.targetPage#">
    <!--- Send an email with an error message. --->

    <cfmail to="#emails#" from="no-reply@site.com" subject="Missing page: #Arguments.targetPage#" type="html">
     #Arguments.targetPage# could not be found.
    </cfmail>
    <cfinclude template="404.cfm">
    <cfreturn true />
    <!--- If an error occurs, return false and the default error
        handler will run. --->
    <cfcatch>
        <cfreturn false />
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
</cffunction>
```

the above code works fine until I change system default page to 404.cfm within IIS settings. On 404.cfm page I only have

```
<cfheader statuscode="404">
```

and HTML code. As soon as the default page is changed the function returns a blank page! how to sort this out, or handling of .cfm pages should be assigned to the web server as well? Has anyone experienced anything similar?

**EDIT** As I can see cfheader on 404.cfm is causing the issue for some reason. When I remove it, the function returns the page!

Comment: This has been discussed before. Read the answers (both of them) to [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18660340/1636917).

Comment: the only problem is that I do not have access to CF administrator due to shared hosting :(

Comment: That shouldn't matter as you can use the onMissingTemplate method within Application.cfc in much the same way. The key is that if you return a 404 header then that tells IIS to run it's own 404 handler as well. The duplicate handling issue that my other answer refers to is because there is one ColdFusion template serving both IIS and ColdFusion 404 errors. You can define different handlers for IIS and ColdFusion if you wish (as the second answer to that question suggested).