# 404 inside application.cfm - yet page loads and cgi variables change?

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion, cgi, coldfusion-10

I'm having a few issues with my site where certain pieces of script were failing within the application that involved checks on things such as the `cgi.script_name`. I've managed to trace this back to an issue which is caused by my `web.config` file. I ran a `cfdump` inside a `cfsavecontent` file within the `application.cfm` and then wrote the file into my stucture and loaded up the HTML page.

I found that at the time the dump was performed, the `cgi.script_name` value was `/errorpages/404.cfm` yet the page loaded normally and the `cgi.script_name` reads `/cart.cfm`? I'm very confused. I've currently disabled **ANY** error setup and it works fine, but within Error Pages on IIS7, i had originally set up the 404 to execute `/errorpages/404.cfm` and under the error feature settings to throw a custom error page when it encountered an error. Does anybody know where the hell i am going wrong?

Comment: I have tried to explain my experiences with ColdFusion and IIS 404 handling before. Read this and see if it sounds like your scenario - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18660340/1636917 (note my experiences are prior to ColdFusion 10 but I'm assuming it still works the same way).

Comment: I just discovered the reason.. Strangely, the lack of a robots.txt file was causing invisible 404's. By this i mean, the page loads, but in the application when i dumped the CGI variables, it had said '404' and the query string ended in robots.txt, added a blank robots.txt file and now i'm having 0 issues. But i want to know WHY this is required to stop 404s.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. They are requesting the robots.txt file, you did not have one so that results in a 404. That is how it should work.

Comment: If the robots.txt file isn't present surely it should just ignore that fact? Rather than cause a 404 and mess up the whole infrastructure of the website. This is the first website i've built - so if this is a rookie mistake, i'll bear it in mind next time. Just thought that robots.txt wasn't a requirement that's all.

Comment: It isnt a requirement.  But if a search engine comes along and looks to see if you have one, it does an HTTP request.  A request for /robots.txt is no different than one for /index.cfm.  if it isn't there, its going to return a 404.

Comment: That is a very good point indeed. I didn't think of it like that. Explains why every page went to what i've read is known as a "soft 404". I'm gonna re-edit my question so anyone with a similar error knows to check for robots.txt. Learn something new everyday!

Comment: Yep this is all working as designed. A 404 is normal behavior. You will run into the same thing with common files like `favicon.ico`, `apple-touch-icon.png`, `crossdomain.xml`, `sitemap.xml`, etc. 404 errors are not a bad thing. In fact you will find them quite necessary when dealing with search engine optimization (along with 301 and 302 errors).  Happy coding!