# Custom error page with 404 status

Tags: iis, coldfusion, iis-7, coldfusion-10

I am showing a custom error page when there is a 404 error. But it changes the response status to 200.

The requirement is to keep the page status 404 and still show a custom error page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

You did not give very detailed information so here is some generic information. You can set the status code in your CFML 404 page like so:

```
<cfheader statuscode="404" statustext="Not Found">
```

But beware that might introduce other "odd" behavior. Like [the connection was reset errors](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4781826). Especially with ColdFusion 10. There has been a [bug floating around for over two years now](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3488063) and it still has a status of "ToFix".

You did not share any information on your setup so also beware that sending the 404 status code from ColdFusion will also cause the IIS 404 handler to fire - [IIS7 Displays BOTH Its Own 404 Message & CF9 Message; Should Display Just Its Own](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18237478/1636917). I go into much greater detail over in that post.

And [here is Adobe sharing a story about how custom error handling between ColdFusion and IIS works](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/onmissingtemplate).

I should also mention that you need to check the `Enable HTTP Status Codes` option in the [ColdFusion administrator, settings page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7ffb), for it to return proper status codes.